# iPython notebook access

Tags: python, ipython

How do I start iPython notebook web UI?

This is what I get when I try to start it:

```
$ ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 29, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 12, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

Comment: You need to install [`pyzmq`](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/)

Comment: Did you install `pip install "ipython[notebook]"` ?

Comment: $ pip install ipython[all]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[all] in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'all'
Cleaning up...

Comment: how do I install pyzmq

Comment: @BillJash Following the instructions in the link above takes you [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq).

Comment: I download but how do I install it?pyzmq-14.5.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (md5)

Comment: I have Mac 10.10. pip install pyzmq-14.5.0-pp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl 
pyzmq-14.5.0-pp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your error states clearly:

```
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

So install pyzmq

Comment: I am trying to install pyzmq. This is the error I am getting. Where I am doing wrong? I am using Mac OS X 10.10

sudo pip install pyzmq-14.5.0-pp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl pyzmq-14.5.0-pp27-none-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Storing debug log for failure in /Users/rio/.pip/pip.log